# Justify a Linear code

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, coding-theory, gray-code

Consider the code $C=\{0000, 0010, 0020, abcd, 2110, 2100, 1220, 2120, 1210\}\subset F^{4}_3$

To determine $abcd\in F^{4}_3$ for $C$ to be linear is to say that $abcd$ is a linear combination of a base of $C$

considering the vectors $0010 , 1220$ a base of $C$ and two constant $\alpha,\beta\in F_3=\{0,1,2\}$ so we have $abcd=\alpha\times 0010+\beta\times 1220\Rightarrow \begin{cases} a=\beta\\ b=2\beta\\ c=\alpha+2\beta\\d=0 \end{cases}$

If $\alpha=\beta=0$ we have a word $0000$

If $\alpha=0,\beta=1$ we have a word $1220$

If $\alpha=1, \beta=0$ we have a word $0010$

If $\alpha=0,\beta=2$ we have a word 2110$

If $\alpha=2,\beta=0$ we have a word $0020$

If $\alpha=1,\beta=2$ we have a word $2120$

If $\alpha=2,\beta=1$ we have a word $1210$

If $\alpha=1,\beta=1$ we have a word $1200$
If $\alpha=2,\beta=2$ we have a word $2100$

as $1200$ is the only word that is not in the code, then $abcd = 1200$

AM I RIGHT?

Answer (score 0):

To make a code with nine words you need exactly two vectors.  Pick any two linearly independent vectors and you immediately generate all nine code words.  For example $0010$ and $2100$.  I picked these due to the number of zeroes.  The nonzero elements are in different spots, so $$a \times 0010 + b \times 2100 = (2b )ba0.$$  This gives us all words with 0 in the last spot, where the first is twice the second.  Our list becomes $\{0000,0010,0020,2100,2110,2120,1200,1210,1220 \}.$  Just see which one is missing from the original list and you'll have the answer.

Comment: To see if this code $C'=\{0000, 1110, 0212, 2011, 0121,1022,2220,1201,2102\}$ is equivalent that one can we compare they standart matrix?

Comment: There is more than one generating matrix for each code, so they may not look alike.  It MUST be the same code though, as it was formed using two linearly independent vectors from the original code.  Both must be closed under linear combinations.

Comment: In this case those code are not equivalent.

Comment: No.  There are many different generator matrices for the same code.  Just because the matrix looks different, does not mean the codes they generate are different.  I used $$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1&0 \\ 2&1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and you used $$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1&0 \\ 1&2&2&0 \end{bmatrix}$$ yet we had the same code and found the same missing codeword.